# Understanding Tensorflow initialize_all_variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, random, neural-network

Why the following code prints 4 different numbers?

```
# Random seed for reproducibility
tf.set_random_seed(1234)
# Random variable
foo = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform(shape=(1,1)),name = 'foo')
# Operation to initialize variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
# Run Operations in session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Loop 
    for i in range(1,5):
        # Initialize variables
        sess.run(init)
        # Print foo value
        print(sess.run(foo))
```

I was expecting it to print the same random value 4 times since I am running the initializer at the start of each of the four iterations.

Comment: You are initializing with a random uniform number. If it was the same value each time it wouldn't be random.

Comment: Then, what is the point of the random seed? How can I ensure reproducibility? @xdurch0

Comment: See @skillsmuggler's response. As such, your program is very much reproducible. If you want the same random numbers every _session run_, you could try setting the seed again each iteration, or just create a random array with numpy once at the very beginning, and use it repeatedly to initialize your variables.

Comment: Note `tf.initialize_all_variables` is deprecated in favor of [`tf.global_variables_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables_initializer) or [`tf.initializers.global_variables`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initializers/global_variables).

Comment: About the question, random operations are stateful. You can ensure that they will produce the same numbers in two different sessions by setting the graph and/or op seed, but you cannot "reset" their state within the same session, and also the "random state" cannot be saved or restored. See [Random numbers in TensorFlow 2.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20181217-tf2-random-numbers.md) for the plans for random operations in TF 2.x which improve these aspects.

Answer (score 1):

The function `tf.set_random_seed()` ensures reproducibility.
Every time you execute the program, it generates the same sequence.

**Example**

```
# Run1
[[0.96046877]]
[[0.8362156]]
[[0.510509]]
[[0.7130234]]

# Run2
[[0.96046877]]
[[0.8362156]]
[[0.510509]]
[[0.7130234]]
```

This makes sure your code is reproducible.
[Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_random_seed)

Answer (score 0):

I think when you're running `sess.run(init)`, it initialises a new random number for the session.

The function `initialize_all_variables()` is just initialising all the numbers as a whole, but `sess.run(init)` is the code where that session gets its own number.

I'm not sure though. I'm unable to replicate the code to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after reading the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_random_seed) and @skillsmuggler answer, I realized that `tf.set_random_seed(1234)` provides reproducibility **across sessions**. I will try to explain it with an example:

If you run variables initializer `sess1.run(init)` multiple times in the same session, it will create a random number every time you run it, since each time it is initialized, it creates a random number.

```
# Run Operations in session
with tf.Session() as sess1:
# Loop 
for i in range(1,5):
    # Initialize variables
    sess1.run(init)
    # Print foo value
    print(sess1.run(foo))

[[0.7720382]]
[[0.8953308]]
[[0.22609258]]
[[0.07619083]]
```

The random seed ensures that if we run the previous code on a different session, the numbers generated will be the same (reproducibility).

```
# Run Operations in session
with tf.Session() as sess2:
# Loop 
for i in range(1,5):
    # Initialize variables
    sess2.run(init)
    # Print foo value
    print(sess2.run(foo))

[[0.7720382]]
[[0.8953308]]
[[0.22609258]]
[[0.07619083]]
```

So, it indeed, ensures reproducibility.